# Radiobutton. Как взять значение выбранного элемента?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

У меня есть обычный `radiobutton`, с двумя кнопками. При нажатии на первый `radiobutton` нужно сделать так, чтобы перешло на другую страницу, а при нажатии на второй `radiobutton` нужно сделать так, чтобы перешло на другую страницу.
Ну как в `listbox`(`selectedIndex`, там хранятся по индексам). В `radiobutton` есть `checked`, только это действует если выбрана любая кнопка.

Вот, как взять значение по индексам если это возможно, или по имени?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Займёмся археологией :)

У меня прекрасно работает такой код:

(XAML)

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Checked="FirstChecked">First</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Checked="SecondChecked">Second</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

(Code-behind)

```
void FirstChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Going to page 1");
}

void SecondChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Going to page 2");
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, вопрос решен

Comment: @marioxxx: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте Chacked change Event.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я есть другой метод isChecked.